# Qt Signal/Slot configuration

Tags: c++, qt, configuration, qmake, moc

I have a matter with signal/slots in Qt 5.6.0

When I try to compile, I get the following error:
I googled it and I found out when I use qmake(which is the case I believe) then I have to do some moc tricking, however as a compelte Qt beginner I did not find the appropriate solution.

Error output:

```
loadtexview.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl LoadTexView::TexSend(class QPixmap)" (?TexSend@LoadTexView@@QEAAXVQPixmap@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl LoadTexView::paintGL(void)" (?paintGL@LoadTexView@@UEAAXXZ)
```

loadtexview.h:

```
#ifndef LOADTEXVIEW_H
#define LOADTEXVIEW_H

#include <QtOpenGL/QtOpenGL>


class LoadTexView : public QGLWidget
{
public:
    LoadTexView(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void paintGL();
signals:
    void TexSend(QPixmap sending);
};

#endif // LOADTEXVIEW_H
```

loadtex.cpp

```
...
void LoadTexView::paintGL()
{
    int w1 = width();
    int h1 = height();
    int w2,h2;
    float r1 = (float) w1 / (float) h1;
    float r2 = 1;

    w2 = w1;
    h2 = (float) w2 / r2;

    if(h2 > h1)
    {
        h2 = h1;
        w2 = (float) h2 * r2;
    }

    QPixmap tex = QPixmap("C:\\Users\\Gabor\\OneDrive\\Documents\\TexGen\\TexGen\\road.bmp");
    emit TexSend(tex);
...
```

connecting the signal and slot in mainwindow.cpp:

```
myLoadView = new LoadTexView();
myGenView = new GenTexView();
QHBoxLayout *TWrapper = new QHBoxLayout;
TWrapper -> addWidget(myLoadView);
ui->LoadedTexture->setLayout(TWrapper);

QObject::connect(myLoadView, SIGNAL(TexSend(QPixmap)),
                 myGenView,      SLOT(gotTexture(QPixmap)));
```

Anyone has an idea how do I solve this? I believe it's just a moc configuration, however, I have no idea how to solve it. Everything else seems fine to me.

Comment: You're missing the Q_OBJECT macro in LoadTexView's declaration

Comment: Yes you are right, thanks it fixed everything!